# Are the PendSV / SVC exceptions raised immediately?

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, cortex-m, bare-metal

I'm working on a context saving and restoring mechanism on the Cortex-M4 so that I can implement simple multitasking. I use `arm-none-eabi-g++` for compiling this code. Portability is not a concern for now.

I use this for a form of cooperative multitasking when a task can call a `yield` function which will make execution return to the kernel by raising a `PendSV` exception. (The kernel can then schedule another task for running and eventually return to the current one.)

```
void Task::yield() {
    // ...
    // ... (Context saving code goes here) ...
    // ...

    // Set the PENDSVSET to trigger a PendSV exception
    SCB->ICSR |= SCB_ICSR_PENDSVSET_Msk;
}
```

**I'd like execution to go back to the kernel immediately.**

The question is, after I set the `PENDSVSET` bit in the `ICSR`, is it guaranteed that execution goes to `PendSV_Handler` immediately, or does it continue executing instructions after the `yield` function?

Would I better off using the `SVC` instruction for this?

```
void Task::yield() {
    // ...

    // SVC has an 8-bit immediate constant argument, which
    // can be used by the kernel for determining what kind
    // of system call this is.
    asm volatile("SVC 0");
}
```

Comment: Surely you'd want it to be synchronous, no? I'm not sure how an asynchronous yield could even work...

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes, that's why I'm asking! Updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description in the architecture manual, PendSV is really intended for when for a higher-priority exception handler to say "oh, the thread I've interrupted is now going to need to make a system call in its own context because of this". If you simply want the thread to make a synchronous system call in the process of its normal execution, that's the sole purpose of the `svc` instruction.

Comment: Thanks! This is nice to know. And in case of `SVC`, is the exception raised immediately?

Comment: Well, I suppose technically you could get preempted by an interrupt at just the right time, but that's not really any different from any other instruction. Otherwise it's an explicit transfer of control to the SVC handler just as `bl` is an explicit transfer of control to some other piece of code, but with the additional context-saving and mode switch.

Comment: I don't mind being preempted by an interrupt, just don't want any instruction after the `SVC` executed until the kernel decides to schedule the current task again.